# How to replace a string with old string+appended string in vim

Tags: regex, vim

This is the text in my file, which I'm editing with vim:

[image]

I want to change it to the the following content:

[image]

I have tried using this regular expression `:%s/^.*$/\g<0>,\g<0>/g`, but it's not working..

Comment: Please don't post text as a picture. Post text as text

Comment: Another alternative you can use also the backreferecing if you want `:%s/\v(.+)/\1,\1/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following replacement:

```
:%s/^.*$/&,&/
         ^ ^
```

The `^.*$` pattern will match the whole line, and `&` is a backreference to the whole match. So, the replacement is inserting back the whole match, a comma, and again the whole match.

**NOTE**: The `^` and `$` in this `^.*$` pattern can be omitted, but a lot of people prefer to keep them explicit in the pattern to facilitate pattern readability and further pattern testing.

**An alternative in case you want to avoid matching *empty* lines**:

```
:%s/.\+/&,&/
    ^^^
```

The `.\+` will match 1 or more characters.

Comment: @Downvoter, please let know what is bad about this answer and why it is not helpful and what research it lacks.

Comment: Don't you think that the flag `g` is useless at the end of the substitution as you are going to select all the line !!

Comment: @Meninx: That is not critical, isn't it? It is again the same stuff as `^` and `$`.

Comment: Exactly I was on the cusp of the stating that but I thought that will be too much ! haha and the question is am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

using `:s`

```
%s/.*/&,&/
```

Note

- you don't need the `^ and $` since the regex is greedy.
- you don't need the `g` flag either.
- if you want to golf a bit, you don't need the last `/`

Or use `normal` command:

```
%norm! yaWA,^R"
```

or

```
%norm! yg_A,^R"
```

the `^R`, you press `<c-v><c-r>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew take it easy.. I never downvote answers at SO. because people post answer trying to help others.  unless it is a completely wrong answer. If I downvote, I always post comment.

Comment: I am  novice at vim.could you explain the normal command for me?thanks very much

Comment: @elsonwx `normal` just like doing keystrokes in normal mode. read `:h :norm`  for help doc.  In this example, `yaW` yank the WORD, then `A` enter INSERT mode, added the `,` and `<C-R>` filled the yanked WORD. (`yg_`) will yank the whole line without the linebreak.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  and  your  answers are  very helpful to me, thanks very much.but WiktorStribizew is the first to answer this question ,so I adopted  his answer.thanks for  your warm-hearted anwser

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without using regular expressions is to record a macro as you change the first line, then play the macro to change the remaining lines.

```
ggqay$A,<ESC>p+q4@a
```

Explanation:
`gg` move cursor to beginning of first line
`qa` start recording into register `a`
`y$` copy the line
`A` go to insert mode at the end of the line
`,<ESC>` insert a comma and go back to normal mode
`p` paste the copy
`+` move the cursor to the start of the next line
`q` stop recording
`4@a` play the macro four times to change the next four lines.

Answer (score -1):

Execute these one by one:

```
:%s/abc/abc,abc/g
:%s/123/123,123/g
:%s/this/this,this/g
:%s/them/them,them/g
:%s/my/my,my/g
```

Similarly, replace the string with desired string for manipulating any string.

Comment: if OP has 500 lines?

Comment: well then I would write a bash script for that which will use capabilities of just `echo` without using vim.

Comment: And such answers are not downvoted, and mine was - I just can't get it.

Comment: `:s` accepts regex, obviously, you don't know how to use regex. to be honest, even if you wrote a shell script, your shell script is not a good one either. regex is very basic and important skill for vim **and** shell programming.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew from your rep I can tell, you are not new at SO. we have seen/experienced downvoting without a reason, haven't we? at least I know it is happening very often.

Comment: Saying, your job can be simply done with using just `echo` and nothing else

Comment: @GirishSunkara I write shell scripts too, well, perhaps not as good/much as you did. But I know `echo` is not the best solution to this problem. The question is tagged by `linux` I guess bash/shell solutions were acceptable as well. You can extend your answer if you like, to add the shell way.