# PHP: how to remove special char(except some) from string

Tags: php, regex, string

Hello i tried below code using regex

```
$str =  preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_]/i", '', 'New_text % *');

//output => New_text
```

( _ is except char )

all work perfect but when my input string something like in other language(ex Hindi), char in Hindi Lang will
also delete.

same as above example

```
$str =  preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_]/i", '', 'कपिल शर्मा % * _');

//output => _

how to get: कपिल शर्मा _
```

is there any mistake in regex or any other way in PHP we can do?

Comment: Use `\W` instead of the full character range. Also add the `u` modifier.

Comment: That `a-z` does not cover Hindi letters should be obvious … those are _Latin_ letters.

Comment: So, what exactly *do* you allow then? `a-z0-9` is simple and specific. *"And also Hindi"* is very wide, vague and unspecific. What about Arabic, Japanese and other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
'~[^\p{M}\w]+~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK0pF8/2)

It seems that PHP PCRE regex does not match combining marks with `\W` and `/u` modifier, so, we need to use the corresponding `[^\w]` negated character class and add a `\p{M}` Unicode property (combining marks) there.

See [more on Unicode properties here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 2):

Use unicode properties:

```
$str =  preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{Z}_]/u", '', 'कपिल शर्मा % * _');
```

Where

- `\p{L}` stands for any letter in any language
- `\p{N}` stands for any digit in any language
- `\p{Z}` stands for any kind of separator.
- `u` flag for unicode

[Documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: it's give me 
 Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p

Comment: @user3736833: add spaces in the character class, see my edit.

Comment: Come on, use `'~\W+~u'`. @Toto: `\p{Z}` does not match a tab character. Nor does it match vertical whitespace.

Comment: it's give me output कपल शरम _ which is not correct i need कपिल शर्मा _

Comment: @user3736833 what is `पि`? Maybe just add that in a character class? It doesn't appear to be a word character. e.g. maybe `[^\wपि]+`?

Comment: @user3736833: It seems that one of the character is not included in the range, I don't know Hindi but if you add `ि`in the character class, it is kept.

Comment: That must be happening because you forgot about combining marks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter_var`

```
filter_var('your string &% * _',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

or if you can smal symbol you can use `str_replace`

```
$arrayRequer = array('*','_','^','%');
str_replace($arrayRequer,'',$yourString);
```

Comment: If you can click `downvote` please, don't be afraid say me why?

Comment: Just because no one explained why, I will make up for it. I have got [a similar downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38012656/3832970) today. Even for a perfectly working and well-explained answer. That is not what SO must be: downvoting because you do not *like* something is definitely evil.